# Load Image through my.resources with string (VBE2012)

Tags: vb.net, embedded-resource

I am trying to create a 5 card draw poker program.

```
Dim Rndm As New Random
Dim PictureBox(5) As PictureBox
Dim HiddenCards As New List(Of String)


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim CardDeck() As String = {"AoH", "AoD", "AoC", "AoS", "ONEoH", "ONEoD", "ONEoC", _
                                "ONEoS", "TWOoH", "TWOoD", "TWOoC", "TWOoS", "THREEoH", "THREEoD", "THREEoC", _
                                "THREEoS", "FOURoH", "FOURoD", "FOURoC", "FOURoH", "FIVEoH", "FIVEoD", _
                                "FIVEoC", "FIVEoS", "SIXoH", "SIXoD", "SIXoC", "SIXoS", "SEVENoH", _
                                "SEVENoD", "SEVENoC", "SEVENoS", "EIGHToH", "EIGHToD", "EIGHToC", "EIGHToS", _
                                "NINEoH", "NINEoD", "NINEoC", "NINEoS", "TENoH", "TENoD", "TENoC", _
                                "TENoS", "JoH", "JoD", "JoC", "JoS", "QoH", "QoD", _
                                "QoC", "QoS", "KoH", "KoD", "KoC", "KoS"}

    Dim ListofCards As List(Of String) = CardDeck.ToList
    Dim Count As Integer = 0
    Dim Selected As Integer = 0


    For intCard As Integer = 0 To 5
        Count = ListofCards.Count
        Selected = Rndm.Next(0, Count)
        PictureBox(intCard) = PictureBox1
        With PictureBox(intCard).Image = My.Resources.CardDeck()
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

I am specifically trying to figure out how to get the selected card from the `CardDeck` string to load since I have a rnd function to randomly generate a card. I want to get this working before I move onto the next part. The error it gives me is this:

> `CardDeck` is a type in resources and cannot be used as an expression.

Can someone point to what exactly I am doing wrong and also tell me how I can load the randomly generated card?

Comment: This line doesn't look right.. `With PictureBox(intCard).Image = My.Resources.CardDeck()        End With` You need to use `Selected`

Comment: What exactly is this CardDeck resource?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use the [With...End With Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and your syntax is wrong that's why you came up to that error.

**EDIT:**

```
For intCard As Integer = 0 To 5
    Count = ListofCards.Count
    Selected = Rndm.Next(0, Count)
    PictureBox(intCard) = PictureBox1
    With PictureBox(intCard)
        .Image = My.Resources.CardDeck()
    End With
Next
```

Comment: I tried using selected like you said, but it still isn't working. Could you possibly show me exactly how it should be written? I would really appreciate it. Thank you. I am still relatively new at this coding.